# How do I give a group of users rights to administer distribution groups in Exchange 2003?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003, outlook, groups

Environment:

- Exchange: Server 2003 Standard SP2 x86 + Exchange 2003 Standard
- Domain Controllers: Active Directory, Windows 2000 Functional Level, hosted on Server 2008 Enterprise x86
- Workstations run Windows XP Pro with Outlook 2003 (greater majority)

Situation:

I have a few users that want to manage their own distribution groups through their Outlook client.  How can I give these users rights to add/remove from these specific Distribution Groups from Outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. Create an OU for the particular distribution lists.
2. Create a security group for the users.
3. Add the users to the security group.
4. Use Delegation of Control Wizard on the OU to grant "Modify the membership of a group" permission to the security group.

Comment: This did the trick.  Thank you.  Is there a simple way to determine which users/groups have already been delegated control over certain aspects of the domain by using this method?

Comment: With Powershell and the Quest AD powershell snap-in, you can use the following Powershell command to get permissions on an OU: Get-QADObject 'ou=DistributionListOU,dc=Domain,dc=Local' -SecurityMask Dacl | Get-QADPermission. Replace the text in quotes with the distinguished name of your OU. Microsoft's AD Powershell might have some cmdlets that do the same thing, but I'm not using them yet due to lack of a 2008 R2 DC.

Comment: I forgot to mention any result of the above command with the "Read/Write member" rights will have permission to change group membership on groups in the specified OU.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article that should help:

http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/news/1119764/Exchange-security-groups